# NGINX Redirect Rule: Subfolder only to HTTPS?

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect anyone who access the admin section of my site to the HTTPS version of it. The current rewrite rule is as follows:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     domain.com;

        location / {
                index index.php index.html;
                root  /home/domain.com/public;
                }

        #Redirect Admin requests to secure server
        location /www/admin/  {
                rewrite ^/(.*) https://domain.com$1 permanent;
                }
}
```

The problem with this rule is it is only forwarding `http://domain.com/www/admin` to HTTPS - going to `http://domain.com/www/admin/index.php`, for example, does not redirect. Any idea how to correct this so that anything BELOW `/www/admin` also gets redirected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the four rules in the wiki entry linked by AlexD.  Regular expression locations (like your PHP location) take precedence over plain static locations.  To prevent that, you want to use the `^~` flag on your static location:

```
location ^~ /www/admin/ {
    rewrite ^ https://domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

EDIT: Also, you shouldn't set your root in location `/`.  Set it in the server and let all your locations inherit the setting.  See [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) 1.2

Comment: This appears to have been the problem - Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Check nginx documentation for description of [location directive](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location). You should use `location` instead `location =`

Comment: Tried that already, doesn't help :(

Comment: There is another error in rewrite statement - you seems to be redirecting to https://domain.comwww/admin (note missing slash).

Comment: That doesn't seem to be causing any issues - when I go to (http) domain.com/www/admin, it correctly redirects to *(https) domain.com/www/admin - it's just (http) domain.com/www/admin/index.php or similar which doesn't redirect –

Comment: You probably have some other rules using regexps like `location ~* *.php$` which has precedence over `location /www/admin`. See @kolbyjack answer how to fix it.